# when I want to change a ComboBox of datagridview, its automatically change all other combos of same DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridviewcombobox

First of all, I must mention that I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988352/when-i-am-adding-eventhandler-on-combo-in-datagridview-its-adding-eventhandler), but it didn't help me to fix my problem.

According to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726180/how-can-i-save-my-datagridview-without-any-databses), I saved my `DataGridView` to an XML file. Now I am going to fill the `DataGridView` when I load the window form using the data stored on the XML file.

My problem is that when I want to set the value of one `ComboBox` based on the stored data, the other `ComboBox`'s value changes too. I want to set each `ComboBox`'s value separately.

My code is as follows :

```
private void WindowSelection_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridSource = DeserializeFromXML();
            foreach (WindowHolder obj in dataGridSource)
            {
                int index = dataGridViewWindowSelection.Rows.Add();

                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                combo2 = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridViewWindowSelection.Rows[index].Cells["Reader"].OwningColumn;
                combo2.DataSource = readerSource;

                int readerSourceIndex = findReaderSourceIndex(obj.reader);
                if (readerSourceIndex != -1)
                {
                    combo2.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = readerSource[readerSourceIndex];
                }
                else
                {
                    combo2.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = readerSource[0];
                }

                dataGridViewWindowSelection.Rows[index].Cells["Location"].Value = obj.location;
                dataGridViewWindowSelection.Rows[index].Cells["AlwaysOnTop"].Value = obj.alwaysOnTop;
                dataGridViewWindowSelection.Rows[index].Cells["AlwaysShow"].Value = obj.alwaysShow;     
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the line where you're changing `combo2.DefaultCellStyle`?

This happens because `combo2.DefaultCellStyle` is a reference to the default cell style of all the combos, so you're not changing this one combo - you're changing the common default style.

If you want the style of this combo to be different from the default one (and from the other combos' style), you should probably create a separate style and set it as the style of combo2.

I guess the statement should look something like `combo2.DefaultCellStyle = ...` or `combo2.SetDefaultCellStyle( ... )`

Comment: I have combo2.DefaultCellStyle but could you please tell I must set it to what value?

Comment: You should create a new cell style based on the current one, and set combo2.DefaultCellStyle to refer to the new style.